# Creating folder patthern in Amazon S3 bucket using Informatica powercenter

Tags: amazon-s3, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have requirement for implementing data into amazon S3 bucket layer from teradata using Informatica powercenter 10.2 Hotfix 1, so the idea is to put the target file in dynamic folder in S3 bucket like s3://amazon.s3.bucket/YYYYMM/Schema/File.csv

I would like to pass the s3 bucket path of the file and the file name dynamically
and create the path if does not exist.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a scenario known as, 'generate file with dynamic name'.
Although i have question on how you will upload those files from Infa box to s3.

Step 1 - Create a target with file name. click on this port.
[image: File Name Port]

Step 2 - Right before writing to target, create an expression transformation with a output port. Put below expression there and then attach with above port.

```
out_File_Name = 's3://<<$$amazon_s3_bucket_param>>/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')||'/Schema/File.csv'
```

Step3 - Probably sftp these files into s3 bucket.

Comment: Thank you @koushik for your reply, im not sur that Informatica is able to create the folder s3://<<$$amazon_s3_bucket_param>>/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')||'/Schema/ in Amazon S3 bucket  before puting the file in it ! Actualy im using the import target ( csv file already existing in the bucket as target with amazonS3 plugin option) so with this i can write in it but if i try to specify a folder path that does not exist in the bucket the workflow fails with error that indicate that the folder does not exist in the bucket

Comment: so you can use a pre session shell script first to create the folder path. can you?

Comment: i guess we can do this even i have no idea how to do it, any suggestion or document to help me to do it ?

Comment: can you check if that plugin can run some script ion S3 ? if yes, then you can use shell scripting and commands like `mkdir`